# How to use java7 to get current Windows time format

Tags: java, time-format

Currently, both display language and format language of Windows 7 are English. So the short time format is "h:mm tt"

Run the following code:

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();              
DateFormat timeFormatter =  DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
String dateOut = timeFormatter.format(today);
System.out.println("short: " + dateOut);
```

Get the result:
    short: 10:36 AM

Then change the short time format to "H:mm", run the code again, still get the result:
    short: 10:36 AM
But what I expect is
    short: 10:36

And I don't want to hard code the format pattern, it should be following the short time format changes.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible your default language is `en_US`. DateFormat.SHORT  for en_US is always am/pm. Just take a look [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html)

Comment: My default language is en_US, and I know java retrieve the default locale information from localedata.jar. But is there any way to get the custom short format from Win7 'Regional and Language Options'?

Comment: set `Locale` according to your need

Comment: I find it is not possible by using pure java. But we can refer the implement of SWT DateTime widget.[link](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/platform/eclipse.platform.swt/+/I20131217-0800/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT/win32/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/DateTime.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String dateOut = dateFormat.format(today);
System.out.println("short: " + dateOut);
```

Comment: Please take a look [DateFormat.SHORT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html)

Comment: Take a look of, a good demo is there [multiple languages for your java application](http://blog.cedric.ws/multiple-languages-for-your-java-application)